# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tmpMonth' was corrupted

Tags: visual-c++

I have a error as title, I delete near all my codes and keep a simple codes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void main(){
    // input Date from keyboard
    unsigned char tmpDayOfWeek, tmpDay, tmpMonth;
    unsigned int tmpYear;
    printf("Please input your date:\n");
    printf("  Day of Week (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday,...): "); scanf("%d", &tmpDayOfWeek);
    printf("  Day (1..31): "); scanf("%d", &tmpDay);
    printf("  Month (1..12): "); scanf("%d", &tmpMonth);
    printf("  Year (1..9999): "); scanf("%d", &tmpYear);

    cin.get();
    return;
}
```

But this error still appear, anyone can help me solve this problem. I use VC++ 2005 and Win 7 x64
Thank,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `scanf` the `%d` assumes to be an `int` and not an `char`. So in your case memory gets overwritten for "tmpDayOfWeek, tmpDay, tmpMonth"...

See also [scanf Type Field Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx)

You can explizit specify a width if you want: [scanf Width Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx)

So change your declaration from:

```
unsigned char tmpDayOfWeek, tmpDay, tmpMonth;
```

to

```
unsigned int tmpDayOfWeek, tmpDay, tmpMonth;
```

and it works...

Also you are using "unsigned" values, that means you shoudl use the `%u` specifier...