# Can not read unsigned char even if give "%hhu"

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem in my codes, it does not work as expect when i read 3 unsigned char from keyboard, i already use fflush() to flush the buffer, but the 2nd variable can get value from keyboard. Here's my codes:

```
void main(){
    // input Date from keyboard
    unsigned char tmpDayOfWeek;
    unsigned char tmpDay;
    unsigned char tmpMonth;
    unsigned int tmpYear;
    printf("Please input your date:\n");
    printf("  Day of Week (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday,...): "); 
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%hhu", &tmpDayOfWeek);
    printf("  Day (1..31): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%hhu", &tmpDay);
    printf("  Month (1..12): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%hhu", &tmpMonth);
    printf("  Year (1900..9999): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%u", &tmpYear);
    printf(" dow = %d\n", tmpDayOfWeek);
    printf(" Day = %d\n", tmpDay);
    printf(" Month = %d\n", tmpMonth);
    printf(" Year = %d\n", tmpYear);

    fflush(stdin);
    cin.get();
    return;
}
```

When I run this code and input from keyboard 3, 4, 5 and 2000 the output is:

```
dow = 3 
Day = 0 
Month = 5 
Year = 2000
```

the value of tmpDay is 0, although i input 4
anyone plz help me,
Thank,
HoangVi
P/S: I use VC++ 2005

Comment: Do you try to save memory using char variables?

Comment: `printf(" Day = %d\n", (int)tmpDay);`

Comment: i ran it with your input and got `day=4`

Comment: My exercises say that tmpDay variable must be unsigned char, so I cant change it to int or other type. When I cover it to int as you say, its value still 0

Comment: @No Idea For Name: oh, I ran my code many times and its alway 0 whatever i input. I use VC++ 2005

Comment: `void main()` is bad practice, always use `int main()`

Comment: i would have post the output as an answer, but it isn't... so go to compileonline.com and check your code ( change `cin.get();` to `getchar();`) and see the magic

Comment: There is no format specifier which allows to parse an "unsigned char"! Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096085/run-time-check-failure-2-stack-around-the-variable-tmpmonth-was-corrupted/18096267#18096267

Comment: @JochenKalmbach wow, complete duplication... i think it's the same homework

Comment: @JochenKalmbach, Idea For Name: No duplication here, that question is mine, but i ask that question when it appear "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tmpMonth' was corrupted" and I already accept your answer, now it make another error, plz read my title again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no format specifier which allows to parse an ´unsigned char´ as a "value"!

Please read the documentation at:

- [scanf Type Field Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx)
- [scanf Width Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx)

The "shortes" value to parse with `scanf` is `short unsigned int` =>  `%hu`

Comment: Ok, I found one way to fix my codes, thank you for your support!